# symfony2のセキュリティーの設定（セキュリティーユーザーをロードする）

Tags: symfony2

お世話になります。Symfony2のセキュリティーの勉強中です。
英語サイトになりますが、
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html
こちらを参考にいろいろやっておりますが、なかなかこのチュートリアルだけではわからない部分があるので質問させてください。
上記チュートリアルのとおりに設定はできたのですが、
1. security.ymlの

```
algorithm: bcrypt
```

と設定する箇所で、他のアルゴリズムを使う方法などを知りたいです。sha1やsha512などで暗号化した文字列をデータベースで保存してもログインできませんでした。ここらの資料がなかなかなくて困っているところです。
またこれらのログインに失敗した際のリダイレクト先など細かい設定はどのようにやればよいでしょうか。
何かしら基本的なところが間違っているのかとも思いますので、ご教授いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

```
algorithm: sha1
iterations: 1
encode_as_base64: false
```

と設定することで可能です。単純なsha1,sha256等は推奨されていないので、ドキュメントでの言及はないようです。（昔は [ありました](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password) が、Symfony2.2以降で変更されました）

ログイン失敗時のリダイレクト先は

```
form_login
    failure_path:
```

で設定できます。フォームログインのカスタマイズについては下記にドキュメントがあります。
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html